# Modified Java byte-code, no difference runtime

Tags: java, byte-code

I modified the byte-code of a third party Java desktop application's `.class` file (and repacked the `.jar`), only to see that during runtime, my change made no difference, unless my change caused a crash somehow. The most simple experiment I did was to use a hex editor and simply replace a letter in a text string in the `.class` file. Runtime (of course, after restarting the Java application), the text was still the original text.

Here's an example of the original byte-code:

```
ldc "Some text."
```

Using a hex editor, I changed the string, and looked again in the byte-code editor:

```
ldc "Xome text."
```

The decompiled code also shows the modified string. There are no more references to the original string in the `.class` file. Despite this change, the displayed text at runtime is "*Some text.*" rather than "*Xome text.*".

Is there anything I need to take into consideration, e.g. some sort of cache (outside the scope of the application) that must be cleared? I tried to delete the "*Temporary Internet Files*" in the Java console, to no avail.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide! :)

**Removed:** The decompiled code and modified files for the real-world application I was experimenting on, due to their questionable nature (didn't really help anyone anyway).

Comment: I didn't get the idea of your question ?!? Could you be a bit more explicit ?

Comment: Are you sure you changed all instances of that static string? And are you sure the string you're seeing at runtime isn't dynamically generated? (Best to decompile the class and find out.)

Comment: The text may have been created by some other `.class` file. Check how many `.class` files are within the jar.

Comment: Can you post the jar before and after modification?

Comment: @Extreme Coders: I unpacked all of the `.jar` files and searched for the string using grepWin within the `.class` files, and there was one more `.class` file in a different `.jar`; however, I deleted this `.jar` since it's not essential, and sadly, it made no difference. That means there's now only a single `.class` (that I know of) which contains this string.

Comment: @Antimony: I can do that unless it's against the rules, since I'm experimenting on a "real world" application and its license/tamper check.

Comment: If it's a real world application there must be some protection, some sort of obfuscation, encryption etc. So my guess is that string is encrypted and only decrypted on running. So you may never see the string in a static `.class` file. What you are editing is probably something else.

Comment: @Extreme Coders: I can decompile the `.class` files and understand the code easily, since class/method names are human-readable and make sense. I'll explain more in just a moment.

Comment: I've updated the question with some code, although I have some doubts that I'm allowed to. The text "Failed to verify the license." is what I tried to change, but the exception message doesn't change at all. Doesn't it look like I'm editing the correct file in the correct place?

Comment: @Antimony: I've uploaded the original `.jar` file and the modified one.

Comment: I only see one jar, unless the .bak file is supposed to be the original jar.

Comment: @Antimony: Sorry, yes. I've changed the file names now.

Comment: Using the little knowledge I have of writing Java applications, I wrote a simple one and modified it's `.class` file, and it was successful.

Comment: Following your suggestions, I'm trying to locate any possible `.jar` that is related to the application. I also noticed that the application caches some of its own `.jar` files and stores them somewhere else. At least now I'm also pretty certain that @ExtremeCoders was right; I'm likely editing the wrong file, or another `.jar` file is overriding the one I edited. Going to keep trying and let you know how it goes! :) Thank you so far!

Comment: I figured out what happens, and this application-specific cache was what had me confused. I tried to mod the cached `.jar` file, and my change was effective! Thank you for helping out! :D

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: Would you mind creating an answer? Although I had considered your suggestions already, you were actually right after all. This application has a few copies of the same class in several `.jar` files, and makes new copies of some of these files at runtime. :)

Comment: I believe an answer to this question would not be right. Protection of software varies and there is no universal answer but if you insist I may post one.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: Yes, I insist, since I cannot even up-vote your comment. :) I felt that the problem was more about the Java environment than the application itself, which someone could have more general knowledge about. I feel content with the advices you all gave (especially you), and combined with my effort, I finally got the result I expected. I'll surely know better next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would mention that instead of using a general purpose hex editor, a dedicated `class` editor would be much better. There are plenty of them.

You tried editing the `class` file and to your surprise the changes you made were not reflected. At that point you should be pretty much sure that there *must* be some other tricks such as generating the strings dynamically, encryption, obfuscation etc.The `class` files could also be loaded from some other locations such as a `cache` which you do not expect.

One way to get information about which classes are loaded is to use the following command line switch while starting java.

```
java -verbose:class -jar <Your jar file>
```

This way the `jvm` will notify you when classes are loaded and from which locations. Using this you can know if there is some sort of *hidden* `cache` from which it loads `class` files.

After this option fails, i.e. when you are sure that there is no such hidden `cache`, you can almost be sure that there is `encryption` involved or the strings are generated 
dynamically. `Decompiling` would help, but of course if there is no obfuscation to hinder decompiling. If everything else fails, you may try inspecting the `bytecode` of the `class`files as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, and for providing even more information! :)